# Android calling Face[] detect with faceAttributesType

Tags: azure-cognitive-services, face-api

I have succesfully implemented the below:

```
private FaceServiceClient faceServiceClient =
        new FaceServiceRestClient("xxx", "yyy"); 
private void detectAndFrame(final Bitmap imageBitmap)
{
    ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    imageBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, outputStream);
    ByteArrayInputStream inputStream =
            new ByteArrayInputStream(outputStream.toByteArray());
    AsyncTask<InputStream, String, Face[]> detectTask =
            new AsyncTask<InputStream, String, Face[]>() {
                @Override
                protected Face[] doInBackground(InputStream... params) {
                    try {
                        publishProgress("Detecting...");
                        Log.e("face", "detecting");
                        Face[] result = faceServiceClient.detect(
                                params[0],
                                false,         // returnFaceId
                                false,        // returnFaceLandmarks
                                null   // returnFaceAttributes: a string like "age, gender"
                        );
```

Now I want to get the face attributes like :

Age,Gender,FacialHair

Question 1:

- I am importing FACE API 1.0 at the moment, is there any update version?
- I am using FACE API on IOS as well and in Android I do not see attributes I can see in IOS like glasses, why?

Question 2:

I need an help on changing the query so it can get attributes like Age,Gender.
I tried to change

```
null   // returnFaceAttributes: a string like "age, gender"
```

to

```
age,gender   // returnFaceAttributes: a string like "age, gender"

or "Age, Gender" , or [age, gender] or [Age, Gender] with no luck.
```

From the interface I see:

```
public interface FaceServiceClient {
    Face[] detect(String var1, boolean var2, boolean var3, FaceServiceClient.FaceAttributeType[] var4) throws ClientException, IOException;

    Face[] detect(InputStream var1, boolean var2, boolean var3, FaceServiceClient.FaceAttributeType[] var4) throws ClientException, IOException;
```

and

```
public static enum FaceAttributeType {
    Age {
        public String toString() {
            return "age";
        }
    },
    Gender {
        public String toString() {
            return "gender";
        }
    },
    FacialHair {
        public String toString() {
            return "facialHair";
        }
    },
    Smile {
        public String toString() {
            return "smile";
        }
    },
    HeadPose {
        public String toString() {
            return "headPose";
        }
    };
```

How I have to format those parameters to get the values ?

Question 3:

I need to gather and work the output I receive from the call. What are the variables of the object returned? Like number of faces detected, age, gender?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. v1.0 is the most current API.
2. The third argument to `detect` is an array of enumerated types.  You can see a sample app [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/Cognitive-Face-Android/blob/master/Sample/app/src/main/java/com/microsoft/projectoxford/face/samples/ui/DetectionActivity.java#L94).  The relevant code is thus:

   ```
   return faceServiceClient.detect(
           params[0],
           false,       /* Whether to return face ID */
           false,       /* Whether to return face landmarks */
           new FaceServiceClient.FaceAttributeType[] {
                   FaceServiceClient.FaceAttributeType.Age,
                   FaceServiceClient.FaceAttributeType.Gender
           });
   ```
3. The response is an array of faces.  The face count would be the length of said array.  The age and gender `face[n].faceAttributes.age` and `face[n].faceAttributes.gender`, respectively.

Comment: Super! I see currently we support: age,gender,headPose,smile,facialHair */ . Any idea when the other values like glasses will be supported also in Android?

Comment: It should already be there.  Is it not?   Here's the complete list: https://github.com/Microsoft/Cognitive-Face-Android/blob/994f0b360aac19f1cbd94c759f494bb6ce8a0552/ClientLibrary/lib/src/main/java/com/microsoft/projectoxford/face/FaceServiceClient.java

Comment: It isn't, with implementation 'com.microsoft.projectoxford:face:1.0.0' I just have FaceAttributeType.Age FaceAttributeType.Gender FaceAttributeType.Smile FaceAttributeType.FacialHair FaceAttributeType.HeadPose. Can you please check?

Comment: Are you pulling packages from [Maven](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.microsoft.projectoxford/vision)?  You should be pulling in the latest version, which is 1.0.394 at the moment.

Comment: Error:(85, 20) Failed to resolve: com.microsoft.projectoxford:face:1.0.394
using 
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
        maven {
            url "https://dl.bintray.com/hani-momanii/maven"

        }
    }

Comment: My mistake - that's the version for Vision API.  Face API is [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.microsoft.projectoxford/face).  Version is **1.3.0**.

Comment: Right ok. Build gradle finished, new values kept. Thanks!